# fetching single value form database in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2012-express

this my database table

## id      name

1         abc
2         xyz
it i enter 1 then respective value "abc" display in different text box???

```
Private Sub butsea_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles butsea.Click

    Dim dset As New DataSet
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim myCmd As New SqlCommand

    Try
   myConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=THEONE\PARTH;Initial Catalog=testdatabase;Integrated Security=True;"
        myConn.Open()

        Dim avalue As String = (InputBox("Input Student Id", "Search Student")).ToString
        txt_id.Text = avalue
        da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM studentdetails where student_id= '" & txt_id.Text & "", myConn)
        If dset.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
           'what should i write here
        Else
            MsgBox("No Record Found")
        End If
       
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        myConn.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add other textboxes for every field you want to show.
(For example a textbox called txtStudentName could be used for the name, and so on for other fields present in the table `studentdetails`).

The correct way to query your database (leaving out other methods like using a SqlDataReader) should be the following

```
  Dim dset As New DataSet
  Dim da As SqlDataAdapter

Try
    myConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=THEONE\PARTH;Initial Catalog=testdatabase;Integrated Security=True;"
    myConn.Open()
    Dim avalue As String = (InputBox("Input Student Id", "Search Student")).ToString
    txt_id.Text = avalue

    ' prepare the adapter with a commandtext. Do not use string concatenation from user input'
    da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM studentdetails where student_id=@id", myConn)
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txt_id.Text)

    ' Fill the dataset'
    da.Fill(dset)
    If dset.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        ' Supposing you have a field for the studentname in the first column of the returned
        ' datatable rows(rowindex)(columnindex)
        txtStudentName.Txt = dset.Tables(0).Rows(0)(0).ToString()
        .....
        ' Set the text property of other textboxes for other fields to show'
    Else
        MsgBox("No Record Found")
    End If
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to fetch just a single value - using DataAdapter and DataSet is overkill. Use `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar` method and in your query instead of "SELECT * ..." do a "SELECT YOURFIELD  ... ".

this way you don't have to jump thru hoops building a dataset, checking number of rows etc. and just check returned value for Nothing instead.

***UPDATE*** Here is your code modified to use ExecuteScalar

```
Private Sub butsea_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)  Handles butsea.Click

        Dim myCmd As SqlCommand
        Dim myConn As New SqlConnection
        Dim oResult As Object

        Try
            myConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=THEONE\PARTH;Initial Catalog=testdatabase;Integrated Security=True;"
            myConn.Open()

            Dim avalue As String = (InputBox("Input Student Id", "Search Student")).ToString
            txt_id.Text = avalue

            myCmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT student_name FROM studentdetails where student_id= '" & txt_id.Text & "'", myConn)
            oResult = myCmd.ExecuteScalar()

            If oResult IsNot Nothing Then
                txt_name.text = oResult.ToString
            Else
                MsgBox("No Record Found")
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            myConn.Close()
        End Try
End Sub
```

This code assumes that database field that u need to display is called `student_name` and that you added TextBox called `txt_name` to your form.

Comment: I've updated my answer with code example. It could be further improved, e.g. it is not recommended to add query parameter to string inline (Google "SQL Injection") so, as @Steve answer suggests you can use SqlParameter to add parameter to query.

Comment: **yep it working**,now if i add **another column** and i want to access that value.then i can use same method OR i need to writing different approach ???@Yuriy Galante

Comment: Your post mentioned Single value only, but if you want to retrieve multiple columns, you need to look ExecuteReader instead.